# How to execute batch file & .exe file using jsp servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am giving input for blast in the `FASTA format`. After that i wants to make the `sequence.FASTA` file in my project folder. And I wants to execute batch file with parameters as `blastp.exe` file, `sequence.FASTA` file, database files, output file.

There is no problem in the file creation of sequence.FASTA

```
 ERROR IN: the batch file is not execute, So the I am not able to get the output file for display.

ERROR is : java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp4\wtpwebapps\toxin-data\outputprotein.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

I have the following code as :

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
response.setContentType("text/html");
PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
String values=request.getParameter("t1");

ServletContext servletContext = request.getSession().getServletContext();
servletContext = request.getSession().getServletContext();
String path="//sequence.FASTA"; /*file is created in getRealPath()*/
String uploadFile=servletContext.getRealPath(path);

File outputFile = new File(uploadFile);
FileWriter fout = new FileWriter(outputFile);
fout.write(values);
fout.close();

servletContext = request.getSession().getServletContext();
String blastPath="//blast.bat";
String blastBat_path=servletContext.getRealPath(blastPath);
Process process = new ProcessBuilder(blastBat_path).start();
try {
    process.waitFor();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();} 
    process.destroy();

    /* to read output file for display */
    BufferedReader br1=null;
    br1= new BufferedReader(new FileReader(servletContext.getRealPath("//outputprotein.txt")));
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line1 = br1.readLine();

        while (line1 != null)  {
            sb.append(line1);
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            line1 = br1.readLine();
        }
        String everything = sb.toString();
        out.println("<pre>"+everything+"</pre>");
    } finally {
        br1.close();
    } 
    fout.close();
}
```

Here the `getRealpath()` is:

> D:\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp4\wtpwebapps\toxin-data

Comment: Are you sure the file is located where you try to execute it.

Comment: You are saying the `getRealPath()` gives you `......\tmp4\wtpwebapps\public_html` and you have a call to `servletContext.getRealPath("//outputprotein.txt")`. But at the same time you have an error message saying it can't find the file at `......\tmp4\wtpwebapps\toxin-data\outputprotein.txt`. These directories do not match, are you really sure the file is where your Servlet thinks it is?

Comment: It`s not about outputprotein.txt. It`s about blast.batch file which is not executing for the creation of outputprotein.txt file.

Comment: ya.. the file is located in same folder for execution